# Getting Quarkus working with podman-compose

Tags: quarkus

I installed quarkus, but it is failing when trying to download resources.  I installed podman, podman-compose, podman-docker and podman-remote.

It looks like podman-compose is not being called by 'docker compose'.  Is there another package I need to install or configure on RHEL9 to use Quarkus?

% ./mvnw quarkus:dev

...

2023-01-31 09:27:25,288 INFO  [ .io/postgres:14]] (docker-java-stream--933788147) Starting to pull image
2023-01-31 09:27:55,287 ERROR [ .io/postgres:14]] (testcontainers-pull-watchdog-1) Docker image pull has not made progress in 30s - aborting pull

Comment: Can you clarify what docker compose and podman compose are doing? Usually when I run Quarkus with podman, I run it just with podman, not with a compose.

Comment: Thank you Holly for your comment.  docker compose is being used as part of a Quarkus workshop to deploy production databases.  The issue is that 'docker compose' does not link to 'podman-compose' in the default RHEL9 installation.  I was wondering if there was a way to configure Quarkus to be more podman-friendly.  I ended up just executing the command by hand.

Comment: I did some work to get podman working well with Quarkus (but I didn't really look at podman compose). There are a few settings that make testcontainers and podman play together nicely, which I've documented here: https://quarkus.io/guides/podman

Answer (score 0):

docker.io had hit a timeout limit.  Logging in cleared the limit and now the skeleton project works.  It looks like maven is actually using podman compose correctly under the covers.